# 動詞＋てか a subtle grammatical nuance or an error?

Tags: grammar

以下の節に出くわして、気になりましたが：

> アパッチ族のあるものは夜中に何を**たくらんでか**詰所の近くへ這いよって電話線を切ったり…

[日本三文オペラ　２４６頁](http://www.shinchosha.co.jp/book/112802/)（開高健著）

学んだ文法によると、質問あるいは疑問を別の句に使うにはまず、その質問の動詞を辞書形に活用しますが、この節はそれを完全に無視しています。

普通に通じるようで特に困ったことはありませんが、どういうことか少し聞かせていただければ、と思いまして。

Comment: ただの間違いだと思います。本にはよくあることです。

Comment: ^JesseGood 間違いじゃないと思いますが・・・。小説など少し文語的な文章でよく見る表現ですよね・・・「何を思ってか、(いきなり・突然)～～」「何を間‌​違ってか、～～」「何をどう・どこをどう間違ってか、～～」「何を血迷ってか、～～」とか。

Comment: @chocolate: いわれてみれば･･･小説をもっとよまなあかん(￣０￣;

Comment: I am not studying Japanese grammar to a T, so I find the answer hard to understand. What exactly does てか mean, regardless of the exceptional presentation in this question? I can not find an explanation anywhere outside of てか as というか. @chocolate I assume you are still an active user. As a point of reference this grammar was used in my intermediate book. To append to user19137's response, is this grammar just inkhorn-ish "企むか"? Sorry, last thing: is it just a participle format that derives from the question clause?

Comment: "For whatever they were scheming, the Apache Clan snuck up to close to office and not only cut the phone line..."; something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、「アパッチ族のあるものは…這い寄った」に理由を表す「◯◯をたくらんで」をつけると「アパッチ族のあるものは、◯◯をたくらんで…這い寄った」と例文のとおりになります。

ここで、「◯◯をたくらんで」を主節にして文を変形すると「アパッチ族のあるものが…這い寄ったのは、◯◯を たくらんで だ。」となります。

この文を疑問文にすると「…あるものが…這い寄ったのは、何を企んで <s>だ</s> か？」と「だ」が消えます。

これを従属節にもどすと「…あるものは、何を企んでか、…這い寄った」となります。

因みに従属節の場合は「だ」を残して「…あるもの…は、何を企んでだか、…這い寄った」ということもできます。

言語は例外が多いので文法の説明はどうしても不正確になることが避けられません。「習ったこと」とちがうと思ったら、たいてい「習ったこと」のほうが間違ってます。

Comment: 素晴らしい説明です。ありがとうございます！おそらく習った内容は「安全性」や「使いやすさ」を優先されたもので、そのためこういう微妙な点が省かれたでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

「たくらんでか」は「たくらんで"なの"か」と言うこともできます。

「たくらんでか」は話し言葉として使います。この文章の著者は話し言葉を意識して書いたと思います。

Comment: 間違いなく、そのとおりです。著者は大阪出身で戦後の大阪のまんなかでの出来事を語り、容赦なく激しい大阪弁もいたるところに入れます。